# How to define a function that reads csv files and divides the colums into seperate arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I need to write a function that:

1. reads the file passed into it (it's a path to a csv file)
2. uses np.array_split to turn the 784 pixels into 28x28
3. converts strings to floats using np.array().astype
4. finally returns 2 arrays: images and labels

This is my code, when I first ran it, there was incorrect output, so I changed training_file to training_file[:, :], but then I get 'no such file or directory' error.

Could you please help me identify the mistake and suggest solutions? I'm quite new to programming and would appreciate idiot-proof answers :)

```
with open(filename) as training_file:
        training_file = np.loadtxt(training_file,delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
        for row in training_file:
            labels = row[0]
            images = row[1:785]
            for images in training_file:
                np.array_split(training_file[:, :], 28)
                for image in images:
                    image.astype(float)
    return images, labels
```

Thank you!

Comment: The `no such file` error is caused by a wrong file name, and will occur in the `open` action.  `incorrect output` is too vague of a description, but implies you got the filename right, and load worked.  Get the `loadtxt` working, and describe the result.  With that call I expect a 2d array of floats. With column indexing you should be able to separate `labels` from `images`.  You shouldn't need the `row` iteration or the `astype` call.

Comment: I'm not sure now what exactly my code looked like at the very beginning, because I tried to solve my issue somehow. Then I got the error that I'm trying to access an index that is out of tuples range. So basically the loadtxt loaded my file as tuple cause there were two ndtypes as the first comuln was strings, and the rest were floats. So now I'm trying to fix the problem  of it being a tuple...